# How do I add multiple custom menu Woo-commerce my account page?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, endpoints

How do I add multiple custom menu Woo-commerce my account page?
this code works but how do i show content for each my custom menus?

```php
function pa_custom_endpoint() {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
        add_rewrite_endpoint( $endpointkey, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    }
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'pa_custom_endpoint_query_vars', 0 );

function pa_custom_endpoint_query_vars( $vars ) {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
        $vars[] = $endpointkey;
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'pa_custom_endpoint_link_my_account' );

function pa_custom_endpoint_link_my_account( $items ) {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
        $items[$endpointkey] = $endpointlable;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: @tfrommen Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
    function pa_custom_endpoint_keys() {
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $phantom_option  = $wpdb->prefix . 'phantom_option';
    $phantom_menu  = $wpdb->prefix . 'phantom_menu';
    $results=$wpdb->get_results("select * from $phantom_menu");
    $endpointsdata =array();
    foreach($results as $row){
    $endpointsdata[$row->pa_menu_endpoint] = $row->pa_menu_name;
    }
    return $endpointsdata;
}

add_action( 'init', 'pa_custom_endpoint' );
function pa_custom_endpoint() {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
        add_rewrite_endpoint( $endpointkey, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
            flush_rewrite_rules(false);
            update_option('pa_permalinks_flushed', 1);
    }

}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'pa_custom_endpoint_query_vars', 0 );
function pa_custom_endpoint_query_vars( $vars ) {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
        $vars[] = $endpointkey;
    }
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'pa_custom_endpoint_link_my_account' );
function pa_custom_endpoint_link_my_account( $items ) {
    foreach(pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey=>$endpointlable){
        $items[$endpointkey] = $endpointlable;
    }
    return $items;
}

foreach (pa_custom_endpoint_keys() as $endpointkey => $endpointlable) {
    add_action('woocommerce_account_' . $endpointkey . '_endpoint', 'tabcontent');
}

function tabcontent($endpointlable) {
    global $wp;
    $request = explode('/', $wp->request);
    $myaccount_current_endpoint = end($request);
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $phantom_option  = $wpdb->prefix . 'phantom_option';
    $phantom_menu  = $wpdb->prefix . 'phantom_menu';
    $results=$wpdb->get_results("select * from $phantom_menu WHERE pa_menu_endpoint='$myaccount_current_endpoint'");
        foreach($results as $content):
            echo do_shortcode($content->pa_menu_content);
        endforeach;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).